# Can I delete the detached folder on clickhouse data

Tags: clickhouse

There are many `ignored` folder in the detached, and take up too many spaces, can I remove it?

```sh
[root@cl1-data4 billing_test]# du -h --max-depth=1 ./tb_pay_order_log_local/
40G     ./tb_pay_order_log_local/detached
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are definitely sure that these data will not be used more it can be deleted from the file system manually.

I would prefer to remove ClickHouse artifacts using specialized operation [DROP DETACHED PARTITION](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter/partition/#alter_drop-detached):

```sql
# get list of detached partitions
SELECT database, table, partition_id
FROM system.detached_parts

# drop them one by one
ALTER TABLE {database}.{table} DROP DETACHED PARTITION {partition_id}
```

Or automate it (idea was borrowed [CH github: Attach all detached partitions #8183](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/8183#issuecomment-612938283)):

```sh
# warning [be careful]: this script remove ALL detached parts of ALL tables
# to affect only one table need to add "WHERE table = 'tb_pay_order_log_local'"

clickhouse-client --format=TSVRaw  \
    -q"select 'ALTER TABLE ' || database || '.' || table || ' DROP DETACHED PARTITION \'' || partition_id || '\';\n' from system.detached_parts group by database, table, partition_id order by database, table, partition_id;"  \
   | clickhouse-client -mn --allow_drop_detached 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete _ignored.

Google translate:

Inactive parts are not deleted immediately, because when writing a new chunk, `fsync` is not called, i.e. for some time the new part is located only in the server's RAM (OS cache). So if the server(HW) is rebooted spontaneously, new just merged parts can be lost or damaged. Then ClickHouse during the startup process is checking the integrity of the parts, can detect a problem, return the inactive parts to the active list, and later merge them again. Then the broken parts is renamed (the prefix **broken** is added) and moved to the detached folder. If the integrity check detects no problems in the merged chunk, then the original inactive chunks are renamed (prefix **ignored** is added) and moved to the detached folder.